# Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 - difference between nesting

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, width, column-width

Using Bootstrap 3.0, what is the difference between -

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
   <div class="col-xs-10"></div>
</div>
```

AND

```
<div class="col-xs-10">
   <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
```

In terms of whether the inner `div` has the same `width` (including `margin` and `padding`)? If no, what's the difference? Any resources where I can understand this better?

Comment: You cannot nest them directly like that. You need a layer of `.row` when nesting columns; see https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E014

Answer (score 1):

The outer element sets the constraining dimension for the inner element, you can see this in effect if you simply do:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9249/)

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-10">
    <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-10"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    height:20px;
}
.col-xs-12 {
    border:1px solid red;
}
.col-xs-10 {
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

With that in mind, the [Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) uses media queries based on pixel amounts to set the behaviour of columns at distinct intervals (e.g. `xs`) as such, elements should be nested in decending order of width out of 12 (the maximum amount) in order for a layout to respond as anticipated to screen size.

Comment: So, why are the blue boxes in your fiddle not of the same size is what I was curious about? Is it because of the default padding applied to all these classes in Bootstrap CSS? Because If I just apply a padding 0 to these `div`s, they become the same size! Check this out - http://jsfiddle.net/3yzq22bL/1/

Comment: Yes- its due to the 15px padding applied to all `.col-xx` classes, see: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9250/ with padding removed